# What does "final" mean in IL?

Tags: c#, overriding, clr, cil

When using ildasm/ilasm, you can observe the MSIL/CIL code produced by a compiler (the C# compiler, for example), and in some cases you can see that there are methods marked as `virtual final`.

What does `final` mean in this context? My guess is that it means "this method cannot be overridden", so even if this method has a slot in the virtual table, that slot cannot be overwritten by a method in a derived class.

But how? How does it work, in practice?

Is it just enforced by the compiler (e.g. if you try to override a sealed method, it will fail with a compilation error) or by the CLR (e.g. when you try the overriding method, the CLR throws), or by both?
Is there any legal way of "removing", circumventing, this `final`, i.e. to write a derived class that overrides this method?

**Update**: I probably have found a way (see my own answer) but I am not sure at all this is legal, supported, standard... so I have posted another question on this new (but related) problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33945666/863564)

I am open to comments and, of course, alternative ways (if they exist!) to do it.

Comment: Pretty much mean the final implementation, no more chance to override. Similar to `sealed` in C#.

Comment: It is intended for the *verifier*, the part of the jitter that validates the MSIL.  Matters to classes with virtual methods, they are very easy to hack.  Implementation is simple, if somebody hacks IL and derives from the class to override the method then the verifier yells and puts a stop to it.  The C# language was designed to never get this wrong but you could hack by using a fake reference assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does final mean in this context? My guess is that it means "this method cannot be overridden", so even if this method has a slot in the virtual table, that slot cannot be overwritten by a method in a derived class.

Yes. It is as such the equivalent of the C# keyword `sealed` so for example:

```
public override sealed string ToString()
{
  return "";
}
```

Becomes:

```
.method public final hidebysig virtual instance string ToString () cil managed 
{
  ldstr ""
  ret
}
```

`virtual` relates to the C# keyword `virtual` but also to any other virtual method. This includes `override` and also any interface implementation. In particular while you can't define a method as `virtual sealed` in C# (because it would be pointless, so you should decide just what you want to do) you can in CIL, and this is done in some interface implementations.

To the C# perspective there are three ways to implement an interface method or property:

1. Non-virtual.
2. Virtual (so derived classes can override it).
3. Explicit implementation.

To the CIL perspective all of those are `virtual` as they all use the virtual-method mechanism. The first and third are also `final`.

(Consider that we can ignore the over-ride mechanism and use `call` in CIL to call a method as it is defined in a class, but we have to use `callvirt` with an interface because we don't know what class we are calling on, so there has to be a lookup).

> Is it just enforced by the compiler (e.g. if you try to override a sealed method, it will fail with a compilation error) or by the CLR (e.g. when you try the overriding method, the CLR throws), or by both?

Both.

The C# compiler will not allow you to override a sealed method:

```
public class Test
{
  public override sealed string ToString()
  {
    return "a";
  }
}

public class Test1 : Test
{
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return "";
  }
}
```

This refuses to compile with compiler error CS0239: "'Test1.ToString()' : cannot override inherited member 'Test.ToString()' because it is sealed".

But if you force it by writing the CIL yourself:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Test extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor () cil managed 
  {
    ldarg.0
    call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    ret
  }

  .method public final hidebysig virtual instance string ToString () cil managed 
  {
    ldstr "a"
    ret
  }
}

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Test2 extends Mnemosyne.Test
{
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor () cil managed 
  {
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance void Mnemosyne.Test::.ctor()
    IL_0006: ret
  }

  .method public hidebysig virtual instance string ToString () cil managed 
  {
    ldstr ""
    ret
  }
}
```

Then if you call `new Test().ToString()` it returns `"a"` as you'd expect, but if you call `new Test1().ToString()` you get a runtime error:

```
System.TypeLoadException : Declaration referenced in a method implementation cannot be a final method.  Type: 'TestAssembly.Test2'.  Assembly: 'TestAssembly, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Indeed, this makes the entire class an unloadable type; it's `new Test1()` that throws, not the `ToString()`.

> Is there any legal way of "removing", circumventing, this final, i.e. to write a derived class that overrides this method?

No. The `TypeLoadException` will happen with any class that attempts to override a `final` method. Your only option is to edit the base class and compile it again.

Comment: Thank you Jon, I reached the same conclusions (I was experimenting with IL too); your example and mine are very similar. Would you care to comment on my last point though? Overriding with a different name?

Comment: I mean your only option if you really need to override is to do a new version of the class you want to override (which is strictly a breaking change, though only rare cases would be affected negatively). If it's not your code, you're out of luck.

Comment: Oh, wait. You mean explicitly saying Y overrides X. That works, but then the chain of names is different for the next derived class. I suppose it could call a `new` X though, which could be overridden in turn.

Comment: Exactly change the name (::X2 overrides ::X), say it overrides the method on the base class (base::X), and the "final" on the intermediate class does not matter anymore. Then in the same class, define a `new` X which calls X2. But it looks... wrong. Or is it something legal?

Comment: I should probably post a different question

Answer (score 5):

This is for methods which are coming from some interface. It is an implementation detail. If a class implements some interface, then the method from interface is marked as `virtual`, that is for polymorphic behaviour (a place in virtual table *(v table)*). But it is also marked as `final` *(Sealed)* so that the further child classes implementing  the base class can't override that particular method.

Consider the following example:

```
interface SomeInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

class SomeClass : SomeInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod() //This will be marked as virtual final in IL
    {
        //anything
    }
}
```

From: [CLR via C# (Jeffrey Richter)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=36tCAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT476&pg=PT476#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> The C# compiler requires that a method that implements an interface
>   method signature be marked as public. **The CLR requires that
>   interface method be marked as virtual. If you do not explicitly mark
>   the method as virtual in your source code, the compiler marks the
>   method as virtual and sealed;** this prevents a derived class from
>   overriding the interface method. If you explicitly mark the method as
>   virtual, the compiler marks the method as virtual (and leaves it
>   unsealed); this allows a derived class to override the interface
>   method.

Comment: It would be marked as `virtual final` if you explicitly implement interface method as well.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, yes it will be marked as `virtual final` in case of explicit implementation as well, the whole point is to prevent derived classes from `SomeClass` to override this particular method and achieve polymorphism at the same time

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was asking a slightly different thing: how does it work, in practice?

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer my own question with a couple of experiments I did, since I wanted to really understand how it works *in practice* (yes, even if it is an implementation detail).

I wrote a class in IL, named C2, which extends a C# class named C1. The method it overrides, M1, is written in IL as virtual final

```
.method private hidebysig virtual final 
      instance object  M1() cil managed
{
   .override N.C1::M1
```

This shows up in ILSpy as

```
public class C2 : C1
{
    object M1()
    {
        ...
    }
```

Visual Studio and CSC see it correctly as M1(), and will call it correctly (tried in the debugger).

Now, this is what my question was about: this should be the last method in the chain, but who says it?

I wrote a derived class C3, which tries to override the method again.

```
.method private hidebysig virtual final 
      instance object  M1() cil managed
{
   .override N.C2::M1
```

It assembles with ILasm, and it produces a DLL.
In ILSpy:

```
public class C3 : C2
{
    object M1()
    {
        ...
    }
```

I used it in a C# project, and it compiles, but when you try to instantiate C1:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Declaration referenced in a method implementation cannot be a final method`

So it seems this is enforced by the C# compiler, not by ILasm (it is possible to override a final method), but it is then checked by the CLR.

The final part of my question: can you work around it?

It seems there is a way. In IL, you can override a method with a different name.
So, we change the name (M1_2() overrides M1()), say it overrides the method on the base class (C1::M2()), *a la* explicit interface implementation, and the "final" on the intermediate (C2) class does not matter anymore.

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit N.C3
   extends N.C2
{ 
   .method private hidebysig virtual final 
      instance object  M1_2() cil managed
   {
      .override N.C1::M1
```

Il assembles, and it shows in ILSpy as

```
public class C3 : C2
{
    object C1.M1_2()
```

Then in the same class, you can define a `new` M1 which calls M1_2().

If you call

```
C1 obj = new C3();
obj.M1();
```

then `M1_2` is called correctly. It seems that the CLR enforces the constraint only if the chain is direct (`C1::M1 > C2::M1 > C3::M1`) and not if you do "jump" over the hiearchy (`C1::M1 > C3::M1_2`). You have to choose a different name, though. If you use the same name (M1):

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit N.C3
   extends N.C2
{ 
   .method private hidebysig virtual final 
      instance object  M1() cil managed
   {
      .override N.C1::M1
```

will not work, throwing the same exception.